# C++ : Unit testing using Google Mock with Code::Blocks, MinGW and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks, googlemock

I've been trying to learn unit testing on my own following along a book.

Code in the book use the C++11 standard and have a line like this:

```
auto variable = function(parameter);
```

When I first compiled it I got this warning:

> warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

No biggie, I could fix that by checking the following box in the Project->Build options... menu:

> [ ] Have g++ follow the C++ 11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]

Now, however, I get new errors related to Google Mock in the gtest-port.h :

> |    | In function 'int testing::internal::posix::StrCaseCmp(const char*, const char*)':
>
> |1719| error: '_stricmp' was not declared in this scope
>
> |    | In function 'char* testing::internal::posix::StrDup(const char*)':
>
> |1721| error: '_strdup' was not declared in this scope
>
> |    | In function 'FILE* testing::internal::posix::FDOpen(int, const char*)':|
>
> |1779| error: 'fdopen' was not declared in this scope

Searching for this problem yielded little for me but I did try and define the target OS as it was a suggested solution in case it was not correctly identified automatically. Adding GTEST_OS_WINDOWS=1 and/or GTEST_OS_WINDOWS_DESKTOP=1 in the projects defines changed nothing.

I realize this is easily fixed in this instance by just providing the correct type instead of using auto but I'd like to find a solution for this if possible. Replacing auto and not having the -std=c++11 option checked makes the code work as intended so the library works.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 , MinGW/g++ 4.8.1-4 and Google Mock 1.7 in Windows.

Thanks for reading =)

Comment: Thank you sjdowling, that certainly worked! Can't seem to work out how to mark your excellent answer as an answer to the question though. I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here lies in the functions which are missing declarations: `_stricmp`, `_strdup` and `fdopen`. The first two are Microsoft versions of the POSIX functions `stricmp` and `strdup`. Note that you are specifying the use of the C++11 ISO standard which does not contain items in the POSIX standard. By specifying `--std=gnu++11` you are telling the compiler to accept a hybrid of C++11 and POSIX along with GNU extensions.

Interestingly I cannot replicate this with GCC 4.8.2 on Linux so there is the possibility that something else is going on in the Google Mock headers when compiling on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for anyone still facing the same issue:
The source of this issue might be in your CMakeLists file.
Set your compiler flags to -std=gnu++ instead of -std=c++
One way to do it would be to include

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++0x")
```

to your CMakeLists file.